# How to add pagination to pageless big JSON file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, pagination

What would be the most practical approach in implementing pagination for a simple NextJs app that uses a local JSON file to load products? This local JSON has no page properties or whatsoever. The only way to "limit" the amount of products shown is with a simple slice:

```
          {Object.values(products).slice(0, 10).map((item, index) => (
              <Product {...item} key={index} />
           ))}
```

I have found different approaches but none that cover it in a NextJS way, where the url changes according to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already consider using query params? You could construct your URL to look like `localhost:3000/page?after=10`. Then you can reference the `after` value in your slice.

```js
          {Object.values(products).slice(after, after + 10).map((item, index) => (
              <Product {...item} key={index} />
           ))}
```

You'll have to create your `back` and `next` links to adjust the values and dynamically create the URL based on the value of `after` though.